# MongoDB "eval" order of execution

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, execution

How using MongoDB shell define function and use it?

In a script file `createusers.js` there is following code to create a user with read role on specific database.

```
function createReader(database, username, password)
{
db.getSiblingDB(database).createUser({
    user  : username,
    pwd   : password,
    roles : [ { role : "read", db : database } ]
});
}
```

Is there possibility to execute this function in mongodb shell? The following call doesn't succeed

`mongo --eval="createReader('somedb', 'user1', 'pass1')" createusers.js`

gives error **createReader is not defined**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`load()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file) to load the js file from `eval`:

```
mongo --eval "load('createusers.js'); createReader('somedb', 'user1', 'pass1')"
```